# Memory layout of a std::vector<__m128i>

Tags: c++, vector

For a vector of 128bit integer type (`std::vector<__m128i> vec;`), are those 128bit integers always put in contiguous memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is the the `vector` guarantee. All elements will occupy a contiguous memory block, managed by the vector object.

Comment: See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector - "The elements are stored contiguously, which means that elements can be accessed not only through iterators, but also using offsets on regular pointers to elements."

Comment: Is the `__m128i` actually some kind of struct? I saw `__m128i {aka __vector(2) long long int}` when I debug my code. In this case, is the thing still contiguous in memory?

Comment: @dotdotdot: Vector elements are contiguous in memory. Period. Whether the logical data you're trying to access is stored contiguously depends on what those elements are. So a `vector<vector<int>>` doesn't have contiguous `int`s because vectors store their data indirectly (but contiguously!).

Comment: I hope that `__m128i` has no padding...

Comment: @dotdotdot: "[Variables of type _m128i are automatically aligned on 16-byte boundaries.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26232t5c.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)"

Comment: @dotdotdot, even if it has padding, it's considered part of the element. So as far as the vector (and we) is concerned, it's contiguous.